# C# System.IO How to get path to a folder in my project

Tags: c#, filesystems

[[image: picture]]

In my program I want to use this image (the image marked in the picture)
but how can I get the path of this picture without using an absolute path (it should work on any pc without changing a path in the code)?

Can someone post a example code of opening a filestream with this picture called "Jonas.jpg"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the path of your application using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

and then use a Path.Combine, adding the local path.

```
Image.FromFile(
  Path.Combine (
     Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
     "Persons/Jonas.jpg"));
```